# How to get global application menu on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.04

Is it possible to have global application main menu in Ubuntu 18.04 (similar to what was available in Unity, with application menu appearing in the top bar)?

There are a lot of conflicting information on this subject on the internet, with mostly suggestions to install some Gnome extensions that are no longer available or not maintained. Besides, most (if not all) of the answers are for Ubuntu 17.10. So I am wondering if there's a way to have it for Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers for Ubuntu 17.10? They're about an older release doesn't mean they won't work with 18.04?

Comment: I did not. The only answers I found suggest installing some obsolete extensions. I just want to know if there's a better way for 18.04.

Comment: Short answer is "most likely no". Possibly the only hope is someone feels motivated to write and maintain another extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> NOTICE: This extension no longer exists, making this answer outdated.  The answer however has been left intact as-is for historical reasons.  It is suggested that you attempt to use other mechanisms to achieve this goal, rather than this plugin.

If this fact matter, I'm the author of the extension:
https://gitlab.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu

I can not speak for ubuntu or gnome developers, but as you already note there are not any official implementation available for gnome-shell or the ubuntu-session.

The **Gnome-Global-AppMenu** extension is supported in Ubuntu 18.04 (X11 session) better than ever.

My desition to discontinued Gnome-Global-AppMenu was base on severals facts that are not really valid rigth now, for that reason the **Gnome-Global-AppMenu** is not discontinued rigth now, besides that, it have improvements.

The Gnome-Global-AppMenu is now using (as a user decision) the fork of unity-gtk-module called appmenu-gtk-module. This is the same fork that is used in Mate and XFCE. Also the jayanta support was improved to really work and more things was added.

After a lot of time inverted to underestand how Gtk, Gnome shell and also unity-gtk-module works around the global menu, with the developer of this fork called appmenu-gtk-module, we were able to create some funtional code for handled the Gtk Wayland windows. Here is the original code that you can install and test from the source:
https://gitlab.com/lestcape/unity-gtk-module

Personally, I'm also want to contribute to enhance more the Wayland support for the Gtk applications inside the appmenu-gtk-module, because the appmenu-gtk-module have just an initial support for the Gtk-Wayland.

Develop something is for me a pleasure and will not be ever an obligation. So, nothing of that means that i will promise not discontinued the develop of this extension or something like that. But also if that happens, the code is and will be aviable for the developers that want to continue with it.

You can check for yourself all that things if you install the extension from his official site in gitlab. Issues can be reported also there.

Comment: It never be "release", or at less not for me. I don't want to pubiched anything in the gnome site. The https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/ is not published be me. Read my own comment there. The appmenu-gtk-module can be download and installed from the ubuntu 18.04 repositories as is distributed with Mate desktop.

Comment: Extension link now returns 404 Not Found.

Comment: Everyone: Though the link 404s now, this post has been left intact for historical reasons.  Please do not flag this post for any additional moderator attention.

Comment: Yes... The extension was finally discontinued. This not means that some one can not update the extension code to be working with the last gnome-shell version. Just it means that i will not be that person anymore. The reason behind my decision of discontinued the extension can be found here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1132 If you have the interest of to find the code of the extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/gnomeGlobalAppMenu%40lestcape.v1.shell-extension.zip Also the most recently version can be found here: https://github.com/jiqing112/Gnome-Global-AppMenu