# GUI issues after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (possibly related to "Gnome global application menu" extension)

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, focus

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS last night and am running into some view problems, which have to do with the GUI.

As a background: I tried to twist the panel view, in order to save space (one panel) and get programme's context menus (*File*, *View* ...). Maybe this has to do with my issues, so here are the extensions that I installed:
[image]

I disabled the "Gnome global application menu" extension when the following behaviour fist appeared, but it hasn't changed since:

1. When I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button, e.g. for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window, the window loses focus and hence the shortcut doesn't work. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-Shortcuts that are not bound to a window (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for command prompt or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) work. Here is how the window behaves, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>:
   [image]
2. When exiting the screen lock, the log-in window freezes after I enter the password the first time. By pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and entering a second time, I can re-enter the workspace, but the Dock on the left side is missing.

Let me know what else I can post to show the issue. I reckon they are somewhat related, but I don't know.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Gnome global application menu" extension has been discontinued and the original developer even pulled it out of GitHub. It's highly recommended not use it (even [by the original developer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032163/480481)). The extension has always been buggy and not ready for daily use. After uninstalling or disabling the extension you need to reset a couple of `gsettings` keys tweaked by the extension to restore normalcy. To do that run the following two commands:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules
```

These should fix your issues (however you will lose the global application menu from the top bar as expected).

Comment: Thanks, pomsky! Any advise on how to get back the context menus without that extension? It's really annoying without them!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way with GNOME 3 I'm aware of. But you can still [use Unity on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481) which has the global menu feature.

Comment: I'll consider it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is supposed that if you disable the extension normally (rigth click over it), that settings will return to the the original values, but if not, this is another bug more anyway. In ubuntu 18.04 the extension should work ok, but not the older version that is in extensions.gnome.org. Instead you should use this version: https://github.com/jiqing112/Gnome-Global-AppMenu The lasted gnome-shell version that is supported by the extension (ONLY in a beta state) is v3.28. Do not try to use the extension in any higer version.